# In MSTest, what does the second argument in Assert.Fail do?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, assert

In MS's docs they mention the following:

```
Fail(String, Object[])

public static void Fail (string message, params object[] parameters);

Parameters

message
    String 

The message to include in the exception. The message is shown in test results.

parameters
    Object[] 

An array of parameters to use when formatting message.
```

It doesn't mention in detail what does the `parameters` argument do. Everything I put in there doesn't show up in the error message, so what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/712ac622df2df1336e83c237e80bb82dfac34684/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Assertions/Assert.cs#L2377) it's clear that it just works like `string.Format`.